# gerar e enviar email com arquivo em pdf anexado com php

Tags: php, email, pdf, phpmailer, fpdf

Em meu script de PHP, preciso gerar um arquivo PDF e enviá-lo via email.
Já consegui enviar um arquivo anexado por email usando o phpmailer e gerar um PDF no browser usando o fpdf.

O problema é que não consigo anexar o PDF no email, já que não está sendo salvo onde deveria (no servidor winscp).

```
$pdf->Output('f', 'arquivao.pdf');
$mail->AddAttachment('arquivao.pdf');
$enviado = $mail->Send();
```

Comment: A minha sugestão seria testares gravar o ficheiro com um caminho absoluto. É possível que o FPDF esteja a gravar numa pasta temporária onde está a correr e diferente da que o PHP está a usar. Controlando o caminho absoluto terás sempre a certeza do local onde o ficheiro está e podes anexar correctamente.

Comment: Acho que consegui descobrir aonde está o erro. Na implementação do FPDF, ele utiliza a função file_get_content(). Fui tentar rodar a função separadamente num exemplo básico, porém a função não rodou e o arquivo não foi criado. Creio que o erro está ligado à essa função.

Comment: Isso parece ser um problema com as permissões onde o FPDF está a tentar escrever/ler o ficheiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, Lucca, eu indicaria a você para criar um arquivo temporário e, depois do envio, excluí-lo do servidor.

Tomei a liberdade de incluir uma função para gerar o nome aleatório para completar o exemplo.

```
function gerarIdentificadorLink($senha = 0, $tamanho = 20, $maiusculas = true, $numeros = true, $simbolos = false){
        // Caracteres de cada tipo
        $lmin = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $lmai = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $num = '1234567890';
        $simb = '!@#$%*-';
        // Variáveis internas
        $retorno = '';
        $caracteres = '';
        // Agrupamos todos os caracteres que poderão ser utilizados
        $caracteres .= $lmin;
        if ($maiusculas) $caracteres .= $lmai;
        if ($numeros) $caracteres .= $num;
        if ($simbolos) $caracteres .= $simb;
        // Calculamos o total de caracteres possíveis
        $len = strlen($caracteres);
        for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
        // Criamos um número aleatório de 1 até $len para pegar um dos caracteres
        $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
        // Concatenamos um dos caracteres na variável $retorno
        $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
        }
        return $retorno;
}

/* Gera a string aleatoria */
$identificador = gerarIdentificadorLink();

/* Indica o caminho destino */
$Destino = '/var/www/html/';

/* Indica o nome temporário do arquivo */
$Arquivo = 'Arquivao_'.$identificador.'.pdf';

/* Cria a pasta temporária para armazenamento do arquivo */
if (!file_exists($Destino . $identificador)) {
   mkdir($Destino . $identificador);  
   $Destino = $Destino . $identificador . '/';
}

/* monta o caminho completo do arquivo */
$caminhoCompletoArquivo = $Destino . $Arquivo;

(...)

/* executa a geração do seu PDF*/
$pdf->Output('f', $caminhoCompletoArquivo);

/* adiciona o arquivo físico ao e-mail */
$mail->AddAttachment($caminhoCompletoArquivo);

/* envia o e-mail */
$enviado = $mail->Send();

/* exclui o arquivo pdf do servidor */
if (file_exists ($ArquivoCaminhoCompleto)) {
   unlink($ArquivoCaminhoCompleto);
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado. Mas o problema é que justamente não consigo criar o arquivo no servidor, porque não consigo descobrir o path completo.

Comment: Cria um arquivo meudir.php e coloca isso dentro: <?php echo getcwd() . "\n"; ?> - Ele vai te mostrar o caminho.

Comment: olá Andre. Estava debugando o script quando descobri a causa do erro: o servidor negava permissão para scripts que tentavam criar arquivos lá. Vou conversar com a minha escola (admin do server) pra me ajudar a resolver. Agradeço a sua ajuda!

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu isolar o problema. Se quiser tentar ganhar tempo, tenta o código a seguir que altera a permissão da pasta. É provável que funcione. Abraço e sucesso. <?php $pasta = getcwd(); if(chmod($pasta, 0755)){ echo 'Permissão modificada com sucesso.'; } else { echo 'Não foi possível alterar permissão'; } ?>